# Mockito: multiple calls to the same method

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

I am mocking an object with Mockito, the same method on this object is called multiple times and I want to return the same value every time.
This is what I have:

```
LogEntry entry = null; // this is a field
// This method is called once only.
when(mockLogger.createNewLogEntry()).thenAnswer(new Answer<LogEntry>() {
  @Override
  public LogEntry answer(InvocationOnMock invocationOnMock) throws Throwable {
    entry = new LogEntry();
    return entry;
  }
});
// This method can be called multiple times, 
// If called after createNewLogEntry() - should return initialized entry.
// If called before createNewLogEntry() - should return null.
when(mockLogger.getLogEntry()).thenAnswer(new Answer<LogEntry>() {
  @Override
  public LogEntry answer(InvocationOnMock invocationOnMock) throws Throwable {
    return entry;
  }
});
```

The problem is, it seems that my getLogEntry method is called only once. For all subsequent invocations, `null` is returned instead and I get NPEs in tests.
How can I tell mockito to use stubbed version for all calls?

=================================================================
**Post mortem for future generations**

I did some additional investigation and as always it is not library's fault, it is my fault. In my code one of the methods called `getLogEntry()` before calling `createNewLogEntry()`. NPE was absolutely legitimate, the test actually found a bug in my code, not me finding bug in Mockito.

Comment: Pretty mysterious.  This should work, generally.  I guess I'd throw a couple questions out there: 1) are you sure it's the entry that is null and not in some way mockLogger being reset to null somewhere?  2) is it possible mockLogger is being recreated without the mocked methods?  It might be helpful to frame the above code in the methods that define it (setup vs a test method).  Finally, you might try a println in your answer impl's (or breakpoints), just to be sure of what's being actually executed.

Comment: Tried to reproduce your problem, a similar approach works for me using  Mockito 1.9.5 ==> maybe you can send the code of the whole Test class via the Mockito mailing list?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your stub should work as you want it. From [Mockito doc](http://mockito.github.io/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html#39):

> Once stubbed, the method will always return stubbed value regardless
>   of how many times it is called.

Answer (score 4):

Unless I'm missing something, if you want to return the same object for each method invocation then why not simple do:

```
final LogEntry entry = new LogEntry()
when(mockLogger.createNewLogEntry()).thenReturn(entry);
when(mockLogger.getLogEntry()).thenReturn(entry);

...

verify(mockLogger).createNewLogEntry();
verify(mockLogger, times(???)).getLogEntry();
```

Mockito will return the same value for every matching call.

Comment: If createNewLogEntry() is called first, then all subsequent calls to getLogEntry() should return initialized entry. If createNewLogEntry() is NOT called first, then all subsequent calls to getLogEntry() should return null. What you proposed is not going to work this way.

Comment: If possible, can you split this into two separate tests cases? One where `createNewLogEntry` is called the other when it isn't? That might simplify things.

Comment: I believe you mean `thenReturn`, not `thenAnswer`.

Answer (score 1):

Am I missing something, or would the following suffice?

```
LogEntry entry = null; // this is a field
when(mockLogger.createNewLogEntry()).thenAnswer(new Answer<LogEntry>() {
  @Override
  public LogEntry answer(InvocationOnMock invocationOnMock) throws Throwable {
    if (entry == null) {
      entry = new LogEntry();
    }
    return entry;
  }
});
when(mockLogger.getLogEntry()).thenAnswer(new Answer<LogEntry>() {
  @Override
  public LogEntry answer(InvocationOnMock invocationOnMock) throws Throwable {
    return entry;
  }
});
```

Only do the assignment if `entry == null`.

Comment: createNewLogEntry() is called once only. After that getLogEntry() can be called multiple times, but it seems mocked version is called only once, after that default value null is returned.

Comment: Seems like something odd is going on. Mockito should and does invoke the Answer each time the method is invoked. Are you sure you are not resetting the mock or entry someplace in your code / test?

Comment: I checked, the only place I set entry = null is in setUp() method as shown above. I do not reset it anywhere in test. I will do some more debugging, but as far as I can tell, Answer for getLogEntry() is called only once. I will investigate more tomorrow.