# How mock all instance of bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mockito

After I try test multithreading application with spring-boot-starter-test:

```
APIConnector apiConnector1 = (APIConnector) applicationContext.getBean("test");
APIConnector apiConnector2 = (APIConnector) applicationContext.getBean("test");
APIConnector apiConnector3 = (APIConnector) applicationContext.getBean("test");
```

This is Test bean code:

```
@Component("test")
@Scope("prototype")
public class Test {}
```

The first instance of APIConnector is mocked, 
but all other new beans are a real class instance.

```
@Profile("test")
@Configuration
public class APIConnectorTestConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public APIConnector apiConnectorTest() {
       APIConnector mock = mock(APIConnector.class);
       when(mock.test(anyString(), anyDouble(), anyDouble()))
            .thenReturn(true);
}
```

Comment: can you show the mock code

Comment: I add mock code sample

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13475057/mockito-multiple-calls-to-the-same-method